# Deleting Beziercurve points that are Z=0

Tags: python, modifiers

I have written a script that imports a surface and (several) bezier curves. I then use a shrinkwrap modifier to put the curve on the surface. However part of the bezier curve can be off the sides surface. Those points are not required and should be deleted. I could do this manually but as I have 1000's of files to edit in this way I'd rather delete them during the import process.

Theses points that are off the surface are at Z=0. So it would be sufficient if I deleted all points that are below Z=0.1. I found a way of doing this with meshes that have vertices below Z=0. However they do not work on Bezier Curves. If I convert the curve to mesh I can do it, but converting back to Bezier curve adds a lot of vertices I don't want.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the selection as shown in the image via python code. Currently my import code stops in edit mode with all vertices of the bezier curves selected. So I need a bit of code that selects and deletes the point that are not needed.

[image]

Comment: Hello ! It seems it isn't really straightforward to do https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99811/how-to-delete-bezier-points-from-curve-splines-with-low-level-code maybe you can filter these points ou at the time of import so you don't have to go back to your curve data ?

Comment: The imports are empties. I convert them to Curve with my code